# Android - Map Pid to Port(s)

Tags: java, android, networking, port

i hope someone can help me. I am currently trying to get the Ports used by an App - in the end I want to have a Java Object to which I can pass the package name of an App and get the used port(s).

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this - there seems to be no netstat od lsof tool on android devices.

I'd appreciate every hint or tip :)

Thank you very much